# Be active a child form by giving its name or its text in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I have a Parent form with some child forms.
Imagine some of these child forms are opened and their name or their text are shown in a something like tabpage. now when i click on a tab page ,the related form must be active.
What can i do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the Tab you want to activate, use the Tabcontrol object to make it active

TabControl1.SelectedTab = MyChildTab